# ID2D1Bitmap1::Map, when can you use it?

Tags: c++, windows-8, direct2d

So I recently went through and converted a simple test app I wrote to use the new version of Direct2D, which means I basically copied the relevant parts of [the Direct2D Quickstart for Windows 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh780340%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  That worked, in that my application behaved as before (just draws a bunch of pixels.)

Previously, to update the bitmap, I was doing the following:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i )
{
    int x = rand()%600;
    int y = rand()%600;
    int index = 4 * ( x + ( y * 600 ) );
    imageData[index] = rand()%256;
    imageData[index+2] = 0;
}

D2D1_RECT_U rect2 = RectU(0,0,600,600);
pBitmap->CopyFromMemory(&rect2, imageData, 600*4);
```

where imageData is just:

```
imageData = new byte[600*600*4];
```

That still worked, but I thought that since I've got this nifty Map method on my shiny new ID2D1Bitmap1 interface that I could get rid of that CPU-side array and do something like:

```
D2D1_MAPPED_RECT* mapped = NULL;
ThrowIfFailed( pBitmap->Map( D2D1_MAP_OPTIONS_WRITE, mapped ) );

for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
{
    int x = rand()%600;
    int y = rand()%600;
    int index = 4 * ( x + ( y * 600 ) );
    mapped->bits[index] = rand()%256;
    mapped->bits[index+2] = 0;
}

ThrowIfFailed(pBitmap->Unmap());
```

This failed at the call to Map with E_INVALIDARG, every time, using various combinations of [D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 passed to CreateBitmap and [D2D1_MAP_OPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the call to Map.

Looking at the description of the [D2D1_MAP_OPTIONS enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it appears that none of the 3 options (READ, WRITE, DISCARD) can actually be used on bitmaps I create with the Direct2D context...

How do I get, in Direct2D, a bitmap which I can map, write to, unmap and draw?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your mapped pointer shouldn't be a null pointer. I suggest to change your code according to the following:

D2D1_MAPPED_RECT mapped;

ThrowIfFailed( pBitmap->Map( D2D1_MAP_OPTIONS_WRITE, &mapped ) );

Answer (score 0):

Recently i dug into this and faced the same problem. As far as i understand D2D Bitmap cannot be locked for writing for CPU. More than that you cant create Bitmap both for write with D2D and read with CPU.

And i'd like to read&write some byte array with CPU and D2D api. But unfortunately i have to use 2 bitmaps created with different `bitmapOptions`. First suitable for D2D api and could be render target for context

```
props.bitmapOptions = D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET;
```

second can be read with CPU

```
props.bitmapOptions = D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CPU_READ;
```

And usage scenario is "render primitives to first, use `ID2D1Bitmap1::CopyFromBitmap` to get data from second (with map/unmap)"